# replace one string with another in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I replace parts of one string with another in javascript? No jQuery.

For example if I wanted to replace all spaces (" ") is "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog". with plus ("+").

I'm looking for something like PHP's str_replace and that hopefully doesn't involved regex.

Comment: What's wrong with regex?

Comment: @MattBurland I've learned or been taught that its best to not use regex when you don't have to.

Comment: Well that's a silly attitude. You should learn how and when to use them instead of believing some silly restriction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Javascripts very own `String.prototype.replace()`[<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to the rescue.

```
"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".replace( /\s+/g, '+' );
```

---

Be aware that `.replace()` will not modify an existing string in place, but will return a new string value.

---

If you for some reason don't want to have any *RegExp* involved, you have to do the dirty work yourself, for instance

```
var foo = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';

foo.split( '' ).map(function( letter ) {
    return letter === ' ' ? '+' : letter;
}).join('');
```

But you would have to check for *any kind* of white-space character here, to be on-level with the *RegExp* solution.