# Combine array in JavaScript with underscore character

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 Var a = "837297,870895"
 Var b = "37297,36664"

OutPut = "837297_37297,870895_36664
```

I tried multiple script but does not working

Comment: split and a loop. Show what you attempted

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive `Var` is not `var` (lowercase)

Comment: Your question is not combining arrays. Your question is about replacing the comma with an underscore and then concatenating the strings with a comma between.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace one string with another in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170841/replace-one-string-with-another-in-javascript) and [Joining two strings with a comma and space between them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20881950/215552)

Answer (score 0):

You can split and map the splitted array as such:

```js
var a = "837297,870895" 
var b = "37297,36664"

var output = a.split(',').map((e,i)=> e+"_"+b.split(',')[i])
console.log(output.toString())
```

> For ES2015 or lower

```js
var a = "837297,870895" 
var b = "37297,36664"

var output = a.split(',').map(function(e,i){return e+"_"+b.split(',')[i]})
console.log(output.toString())
```

Comment: @jaivBhp Getting error - Error at line 6, character 31: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: arrow function.

Comment: Rahul, it's 2022. Maybe time to update your development profile.

Comment: Yes but you can also not use the arrow function. But i suggest to update you javascript to latest ecmascript

Comment: Better yet, understand what the functions do, so that you can do them without the specific functionality available.

Answer (score -1):

You can start by converting the two strings (lists) into arrays using `.map()` and `.split()` methods.
Then use `.map()` and `.join()` methods to produce the desired string (list):

```js
const a = "837297,870895";
const b = "37297,36664";

const [c,d] = [a,b].map(e => e.split(','));

const output = c.map((e,i) => `${e}_${d[i]}`).join();

console.log( output );
```